# Sem a opção de arredondar pra zero em C#

Tags: c#

Eu olhei a documentação da microsoft e vi que a biblioteca `Math` tem `MidpointRouding.ToZero` para arredondar os numeros para inteiros, porem no meu visual studio nao existe esse metodo, apenas o `.AwayFromZero` e `.ToEven`, alguem ja se depararou com esse problema ou sabe como eu posso resolver para meus valores nao serem arredondados para maiores??

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o código para que possamos ver a forma que você está implementando.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito provavelmente você está consultando a página da Microsoft para a versão .NET 5/6 e você está usando o .NET Framework.

.NET 5/6

[image: .NET 5]

.NET Framework

[image: .NET Framework]